# Delete recursive subfolders with find

Tags: linux, command-line, find, rm, recursive

I need to delete recursive subfolders in a single line.

For one subfolder:

```
find folder -name "subfolder" -exec rm -r "{}" \;
```

or

```
find folder -name "subfolder" -type d -exec rm -r "{}" \;
```

But in the case of several subfolders in a single line? (subfolder1, subfolder2 or foo, bar, dummy…)

Comment: -name "folder1 -o -name "folder2" -o -name "folder3" ...

Comment: -name "foo" -o -name "bar" -o -name "dummy" doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do :

```
find folder -name "subfolder[0-9]*" -exec rm -r {} \;
```

using a [glob](/questions/tagged/glob)

or

```
find folder \( -name 'foo' -o -name 'bar' -o name 'base' \) -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: yes but in the case of subfolder name is "economy, bank, data, etc"

Comment: or bank* (bank, banking etc)

Comment: name "foo" not 'foo'

Comment: ??? Is this change anything if you are not using a variable inside single quotes ? :D

Comment: sorry but this command does not work

Comment: not find and delete subfolders. Example: find folder -name 'education' -o -name 'bank*' -o -name 'government' -exec rm -r {} \ don't anything

Comment: "folder" doesn't work too

Comment: only delete last one. Example: -name 'education' -o -name 'bank*' -o -name 'government' or -name "education" -o -name "bank*" -o -name "government" delete only government subfolder (not bank* or education)

Comment: Post edited, retry

Answer (score 0):

The author of the question provided the following solution, which is apparently derived from [the answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058921/how-to-recursively-delete-multiple-files-with-different-extensions).

> I found the solution in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058921/how-to-recursively-delete-multiple-files-with-different-extensions)
>
> ```
> find folder \( -name 'foo*' -or -name 'bar' -or -name 'dummy*' \) -exec rm -r {} \;
> ```